# What is definition of truncated polynomial?

Tags: cryptography, algebra, ntruencrypt, ntrusign

In NTRUEncryption, I seen the **trucated polynimials**, but I cannot understand the trunacated polynomial calculation.
So, could tell me anyone How we calculate the truncated polynomial?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not directly related to programming. [crypto.se] or [math.se] are better suited for questions like this.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Mathematics Stack Exchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Also see OnBoard Security's [NTRU Resources](https://www.onboardsecurity.com/products/ntru-crypto/ntru-resources).

Answer (score 2):

The polynomials are truncated in the sense that they only have coefficients up to a certain degree.

Here is how you truncate the product of two truncated polynomials (the sum is trivial):

Assume you have two truncated polynomials, i.e. two polynomials of degree no greater than `n-1`

```
a = a[0] + a[1]X + ... + a[n-1]X^(n-1)
b = b[0] + b[1]X + ... + b[n-1]X^(n-1)
```

Then their "truncated" product is defined as the polynomial

```
a * b = c[0] + c[1]X + ... +c[n-1]X^(n-1)
```

where the `c[k]` coefficients are computed as follow:

1. Reverse `b[0]..b[n-1]` to get `b[n-1]..b[0]`.
2. Rotate the result of step 1 above `k+1` times to the right and get `b[k]..b[0]b[n-1]..b[k+1]`
3. Denote with `b_k[0]..b_k[n-1]` the array calculated in 2.

Now define

```
c[k] = a[0]b_k[0] + a[1]b_k[1] + ... + a[n-1]b_k[n-1].
```

This operation can also be made by multiplying the polynomials `a` and `b` in the usual way and then truncating the result to the degree `n-1`. The reason for the algorithm above is to avoid computing coefficients that will not be used in the final result.